# how to show different value of single store in 2 combo box?

Tags: extjs4, store

I have Problem with Store in ExtJS 4. In my application I want to use two combo. A store values are displaying in both combo.  But the problem is the value selected in first combo should not get shown in next combo. Due to single store I'm unable to make it happen..What should have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works for me

```
listeners : {
               expand: function() {
               boxerListStore.filter(function(r) {
                       var value = r.get('id');                       
                       var getValue = Ext.getCmp('boxer2').getValue();                           
                       return (value != getValue);
               });
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` event of first combo like -

```
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, records, eOpts){
            Ext.getCmp('secondCombo').select(records[0]);
        }
    }
```